# Laravel 5.4: What is the best way to create routes based on user logged in or logged out

Tags: laravel-5, composer-php

So, I have an API endpoint `/api/v1/xxx` that calls a single controller and method.

In the `routes/api.php` I have added the following logic

```
if (Auth::guard('api')->guest()) {
    Route::post('xxx', 'API\v1\XXController@xx');
} else {
    Route::post('xxx', 'API\v1\XXController@xx')->middleware('auth:api');
}
```

Everything works except when I run `composer install`, I get the following error:

```
a@b /var/www/html/test/app13 $ composer install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postInstall
> php artisan optimize


  [LogicException]                                                             
  Key path "file:///var/www/html/test/app13/storage/oauth-public.key" does not exist or is not readable                                                   


Script php artisan optimize handling the post-install-cmd event returned with error code 1
```

Removing the lines in `routes/api.php` does not output that ^ error when I run `composer install`.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

> Key path "file:///var/www/html/test/app13/storage/oauth-public.key" does not exist or is not readable

This above lines says everything, you have `laravel/passport` installed and enabled but you forget to generate the key,

run command

```
php artisan passport:install
```

and it will work just fine.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it does not allow me to run any php artisan command with that route enabled

Comment: Well then it is more simple, comment these lines, run php artisan passport:install, uncomment these lines and run composer install

Comment: I dont think this is a possible solution, its more of a "jugaad".

Comment: I hoped you would think so, actually when you run a artisan/composer command, it loads all service providers and verify few things like auth, routes and in ur case route is using api so passport, you should have done this before using the api guard, https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport

Comment: What i mean is actually this is not "jugaad" or "hack" this was the right way, which you skipped earlier

Comment: Even if this is not a hack, as you claim, this will not work for me because I have an automated deployment system that runs composer install, php artisan passport:install and various other commands, and this will surely fail on the server at the time of deployment. Actually let me rephrase my question. Is there anyway I can create a route for one controller and one method for both logged in and guest users?

Comment: Thanks for your prompt replies. Also please note that I am using the "auth:api" middleware for the logged in users as its a REST API.

Comment: you mean you're using api guard with email/password based token system. right ?

Comment: Correct. JWT authentication to be more precise.